# Find Next to Last Element in PHP Foreach

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, foreach

I need to write a script that returns the next-to-last element in a foreach loop. Something like the below concept. How would I go about doing so?

```
foreach($row as $r) {
    if (element index is last - 1) {
        echo "The next-to-last element is" . $r;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just get the keys of your array into a variable and then check if the current key of the iteration is equal to the penultimate key.

```
$keys = array_keys($row);
$penultimatekey = count($row)-2 >= 0 ? count($row)-2 : 0;

foreach($row as $k => $r) {
    if ($k == $keys[$penultimatekey]) {
        echo "The next-to-last element is" . $r;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would move the `count($row)-2` part out to a variable before the foreach so you're not doing that calculation each time, and not using it twice.

Comment: Plus, it should always be set.

Comment: `$keys = array_keys($row);
$nextToLast = $keys[count($keys)-2];
foreach($row as $k => $r) {
    if ($k === nextToLast) {
        echo "The next-to-last element is" . $r;
    }
}`

Comment: @Jessica updated. Even with some error checking. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

Move the pointer to the end, then rewind it by one spot. No extra loops or counting the array.

```
end($row);
prev($row);
echo "The next-to-last element is: " . current($row);
```